# MVC route not getting called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this route registered:

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Manager",
                "manage/{id}/{action}",
                new { action = "index", controller = "manage", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "Web.Areas.Books.Controllers" }
            );
```

Then I have these 2 urls:

```
http://<site>/manage         <-- hits the index action of managecontroller
http://<site>/manage/publish <-- ALSO HITS INDEX VIEW even I have publish action
```

What can be missing?

Basically, I need one route to serve all of these:

```
http://<site>/manage         <-- should go to index action
http://<site>/manage/publish <-- should go to publish action
http://<site>/manage/delete <-- should go to delete action
http://<site>/manage/123123/update <-- should go to update action
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting second segment to be binded to action parameter but in your route it is id parameter.

```
"manage/{id}/{action}"
```

With `/manage/publish` URL, id parameter will have the value of `publish`.

Framework can't find an action parameter, so it uses the default value and redirects it to Index action. You can only have the parameters at the end as optional.

If you have to specify and integer id in the middle, you can make it work by defining a constraint.

```
context.MapRoute(
                "Manager",
                "manage/{id}/{action}",
                new { action = "index", controller = "manage" },
                new { id = @"\d+" }, //second segment has to be an integer
                new string[] { "Web.Areas.Books.Controllers" }
            );
```

Other URLs should fall back to default route and work.

Comment: @Projapati You need to create a custom view engine for what you need.

Comment: @Projapati Try the route I posted.

Comment: I ended up changing the route from /{id}/{action} to {action}/{id}